# WordPress callback page fwrite not writing the correct output string

Tags: php, wordpress

Need a little insight. I'm writing a callback page for WordPress, which seems to work, except that my `fwrite` isn't writing the correct string to a file.

What I want to happen is to record `$_REQUEST` data to a file.

Code:

```
    if( isset($_REQUEST) ){
        $t = date('Y-m-d_h-i-s', $timestamp);
        $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $filename= $DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/wp-content/themes/my-theme/callback/inbound_' . $t . ".html";
        $array = array("test" => "1");

        ob_start();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        echo "</pre>";
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $handle = fopen($filename,"w");
        fwrite($handle,strlen($output));
        fclose($handle);

        echo $output;

    }
```

I can see from the output to the screen that the data is correctly being written to string:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1
    [woocommerce-login-nonce] => 
    [_wpnonce] => 
    [woocommerce-reset-password-nonce] => 
    [woocommerce-edit-address-nonce] => 
    [save-account-details-nonce] => 
)
```

...but the resulting file has this content:

```
211
```

Outputting to the screen yields correct behavior, but writing the same string to a file gives me a number, 211 (or some other numbers, depending on the string).

What am I overlooking, please?

** UPDATE **
It's always the stupid stuff you overlook.

wrong:

```
fwrite($handle,strlen($output));
```

right:

```
fwrite($handle,$output,strlen($output));
```

Comment: _"What am I overlooking, please?"_ - that the actual content of a string variable, is something else than the _length_ of that content? You are writing the latter to your file - `fwrite($handle,strlen($output));`

Comment: @CBroe face palm. Thank you.